# cannot resolve floatinbuttonAction and snackbar

Tags: android, floating-action-button, snackbar

I'm very new to the android development. I imported my friend's project in my android studio and I'm having this trouble right now that I'm unable to sort out on my own. Please help me fix it.[image: can't resolve FloatingActionButn and Snackbar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` and `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar` lies under `design-support` library. You have to add `design-support` library into your project.

Add below `dependencies` into your `app` modules `build.gradle` file and `Sync` .

```
dependencies {
    ............
    ................

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If my answer seems useful please vote it up. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the design support library in your `build.gradle` :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

> FloatingActionButton and snackbar are components of design LIB

Add this in your app gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```